# iPad launch images sizes?

Tags: ios, image, ipad, launch, image-size

I'm about to create the launch images for an universal iOS app, and reviewing the launch images related sections in both [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1) and [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12), I've found that the sizes of launch images for iPad are different in each document: the former says that a portrait launch image should be 768x1024 (std resolution), and the latter that it should be 768x1004 (std resolution). I guess that 20-pixel difference is due to considering or not the status bar. What size should I consider? Should I include the status bar?

Thanks

**EDIT:** It seems that the 768x1004 size is for iOS 6.1 and below, and 768x1024 for iOS 7 and above. So, does that mean that the launch image for iOS 6.1 and prior should not include the status bar?

Comment: Good point.
Here is what I found:
[sizes](http://readysteadyapp.com/temp/ipad.PNG).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked in Xcode:

Portrait Non-Retina 768x1024

Portrait Retina 1536x2048

[image: iPad backgroud sizes]

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that, for some reason, I've read a printed version of the `iOS App Programming Guide` with date 2013-10-23 that stated the size to 768x1004, but following the link I posted, it is also stated to 768x1024. The date of the last update in the link is 2013-10-23, so, was the document corrected the same day? Nevermind, it looks that it definitely needs to be 768x1024.

Answer (score 0):

**768 x 1004 pixel with minimum 72 dpi** is valid size of iPad Portrait mode because if you trying to add 768 x 1024 pixel image that XCode Shows warning to you.

i used following size for iPad:

iPad Portrait mode : 768 x 1004 pixel with minimum 72 dpi

iPad Retina Portrait mode : 1536 x 2008 pixel with minimum 72 dpi

Comment: Thanks. Those sizes seem to be for iOS 6.1 version and prior, why the difference? Should those versions not include the status bar in the launch image?

Comment: @AppsDev as per the new iOS 7.0 apple's new GUI they told all to use full screen so, they make UINavigationBar and StatusBar to translucent. i think this is the reason of 20 pixel error to version of iOS 6.1 and prior. if you are using XCode 5 use 768 x 1024 and if you are using XCode 4.6 and prior than use 768 x 1004.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5 but my app is targeting iOS 5+, so I suppose I need both sizes... thanks

Comment: i think you should have to use 768 * 1024 size if you are using full screen else use 768 * 1004.. its just my suggetion...

Comment: "72 dpi"??? This isn't the 1990s anymore, my friend. Screen dpi's have been upwards of 100 standard for about 15 years. Anyway, the dpi is actually completely irrelevant here, because the only thing that's relevant here is the pixel dimensions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Portrait Non-Retina 768x1024

Portrait Retina 1536x2048

Landscape Non-Retina 1024x768

Landscape Retina 2048x1536

min dpi 72

[image: Just In Case]

Answer (score 0):

For iPad portrait:

```
Retina:        1536 x 2048 pixels

Non-Retina:    768 x 1024 pixels (standard resolution)
```

For iPad landscape:

```
Retina:        2048 x 1536 pixels

Non-Retina:    1024 x 768 pixels (standard resolution)
```

To know for all devices follow this(Apple Document) [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)